# How can i resolve ''NoneType' object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a small script for scraping and I ran into the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

I have never before seen this error, so I have no idea what it means.

```
import bs4
import requests

myUrl = "https://www.houzz.com/professionals/searchDirectory? topicId=11785&query=Interior+Designers+%26+Decorators&location=Texas&distance=0&sort=4"                                                
data=requests.get(myUrl)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
listing = soup.find_all('div', class_="hz-pro-search-result__profile- desc")
for li in listing:
  myurl = li
  res = myurl.a['href']
  print(res)
```

The error:

```
File "C:\Users\Hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Hp/.spyder-py3/houzz.py", line 20, in <module>
res = myurl.a['href']

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It means `myurl.a` is `None`…

Comment: It shouldn't be None. @deceze

Comment: Well, it *is*. Check what exactly you're dealing with. `print(li)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the divs doesn't contain the anchor link, it contains a paragraph tag instead.
The following code is probably what you need.

```
import bs4
import requests

myUrl = "https://www.houzz.com/professionals/searchDirectory?topicId=11785&query=Interior+Designers+%26+Decorators&location=Texas&distance=0&sort=4"                                                
data=requests.get(myUrl)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
listing = soup.find_all('div', class_="hz-pro-search-result__profile-desc")
listing = [i for i in listing if i] 
for li in listing:
    if li.a:
        res = li.a['href']
        print(res)
    else:
        print("Error: "+li)
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it finally.

Answer (score 1):

my URL is probably returning `None` so you can do nothing with it. Check your HTML code for li object in this div with such a class. I think the y not exist

Comment: listing have array of data. if listing gave data then it should also have data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css selector.

```
import bs4
import requests

myUrl = "https://www.houzz.com/professionals/searchDirectory? topicId=11785&query=Interior+Designers+%26+Decorators&location=Texas&distance=0&sort=4"
data=requests.get(myUrl)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
res=[a['href'] for a in soup.select('div.hz-pro-search-result__profile-desc > a')]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually specifically want the link to each listings houzz.com page then you need the following (bs4 7.7.1). We take the header url for each listing by class `hz-pro-search-result__name-rating`, then restrict to first `a` tag within. Each `a` tag has an `href` so no risk of `None` here.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.houzz.com/professionals/searchDirectory?%20topicId=11785&query=Interior+Designers+%26+Decorators&location=Texas&distance=0&sort=')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
listings = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('.hz-pro-search-result__name-rating > a:first-child')]
```